# Docker "copy" fails after update

Tags: php, docker

After updating docker, I cannot seem to use the `copy` or `add` anymore in the build process.

> failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 78c8e94f-f1fc-48b5-a2d8-11b2cbd70059::c6q999zij48nd1hj5clokdx04: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2312163789/app/apache: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2312163789/app/apache: no such file or directory

This is my directory scheme:

```
backend
│
└───docker
    │
    ├───app
    │   │
    │   ├───php
    │   │   └───app.ini
    │   │
    │   └───app.dockerfile
    │
    └───docker-compose.yml
```

the `docker-compose.yml` file has this setup:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: docker
      dockerfile: app/app.dockerfile
```

my `app.dockerfile` has a step that runs this command:

> COPY app/php/app.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/

But then I get the error shown above.

Moving app.ini to the same level as the dockerfile, and running `COPY app/app.ini` I instead get this error:

> failed to solve: changes out of order: "app/app.ini" ""

This setup worked totally fine before I updated docker desktop..

Current version: Docker Desktop 4.27.0 (Docker version 25.0.1)

**What am I missing?**

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/47231
https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/2218
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13889
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/11421

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that BuildKit is the cause and issue.

See https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/4594

Solution:

> DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker-compose build